# scipy misc imread from web url

Tags: python, scipy, imread

Is there possible to imread image from web url using scipy misc, or am I obliged to save the image from web then imread and delete it? I could not find an elegant solution.

```
from scipy.misc import imread

url = 'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRtUPjSSDzevfy47QqVpd8v2Nrt49QNIXeAfE9ntEwYKJtnDZabwg'

img = imread(url, mode='RGB')
```

Answer (score 3):

[`imread`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imread.html) takes either a file name or a file object. You can open a url like a file with [`urllib.request.urlopen`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlopen)(Python 3) and pass the file object to `imread`.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from scipy.misc import imread

url = 'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRtUPjSSDzevfy47QqVpd8v2Nrt49QNIXeAfE9ntEwYKJtnDZabwg'

with urlopen(url) as file:
    img = imread(file, mode='RGB')
```

For Python 2: [`urllib2.urlopen`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlopen)